# Mac OS X Java Swing Buttons are Disabled for no aparent reason

Tags: java, macos, swing, button

I wrote an application in Java and when it runs on one customer's computer running OS X The Save and Export buttons are disabled. (Everything else works in the application.)

Both of these buttons open up a standard save file dialog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the save & Export buttons something you wrote?  The Export button doesn't sound familiar for any dialogs I know.

Comment: I just implemented JButtons that when pressed open the standard Save diablog.

Comment: I think we need more information to answer your question.  do you have any example code?   You aren't doing any setEnabled/isEnabled things, property listeners or anything else to determine the state of your buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by misinformation recieved from the customer.

Turns out the customer was trying to save to a location where files can't be saved on his/her hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that these buttons open a file dialog probably has nothing to do with it being disabled. Buttons can end up being disabled for a number of reasons,

- its `setEnabled` can be called with `false`,
- when using an action, its `setEnabled` can be called with `false`, and
- when using an action, it can have a property "enabled" that potentially disables it; see [Action](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) for more information, there's a list of properties there.

Could you post how you 'implemented the JButtons'?

Comment: Could you expand on 
when using an action, it can have a property "enabled" that potentially disables it.?

I'll post implementation later today when  I have code in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark, but most macs are still running Java 1.5; check if your current code misbehaves with Java 1.5 on your end. Maybe that's where you problem lies.